# LibreOffice Calc - apply style to neighbouring cells

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc, styles

I have a column with data and I applied a style to it with the help of `Conditional Formatting`. I now wish to apply the outcome of that style to the neighbouring column that holds other data.

Here is what I mean; the second column holds the data that I applied the style to (with `Conditional Formatting`). Now I would like to have that style also applied to the third column (%), so if the value is marked bold in the second column I would like to have it bold in the third as well.

[image]

I cannot simply paste the style because the conditions of `Conditional formatting` will then be pasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file with solution is shared [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0HwU0hzcrxVMnlvN2FDNEs5Sk0/edit?usp=sharing).

### Explaining:

Supposing the logic used is following:

- if data is less or equal 3 → font is gray bold
- if data is greater or equal 10 → font is bold

And the columns given by you on that example are from **A** to **C**, and from **1** to **14**...

You just have to do the following:

1. Select **C2**;
2. Go to **Format** → **Conditional Formatting** → **Condition...**;
3. For the type of conditions, select `Formula is` instead of `Cell value is` (it is the first important point);
4. For that example, insert following for conditions (note that formulas are made without the `$` to use them relative when pasting format to the below cells on 6th step - it is the second important point; you can use `$` only on `B` of that formulas to lock it when copying formatting to other columns you add...):

   - 1st condition:

     - Type: `Formula is`
     - Formula: `B2 <= 3`
     - Style: Grey Bold
   - 2st condition:

     - Type: `Formula is`
     - Formula: `B2 >= 10`
     - Style: Bold
5. Well, **C2** is ok, so copy that cell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>);
6. Then select other cells from **C** column (from **C3** to **C14**, or just press on the column to select all column);
7. Do **Paste Special...** (with right button of mouse on selection) and mark only **Formats** (the penultimate important point), and voilà - be happy and make me too earning more points from accepted answer ;)

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure how to use `The formula is` within the Conditional Formatting dialog. This is the answer :)

Comment: I learn it today only to earn points :p